# Allow trusted location in my network

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I try to **allow trusted location** in regestry for my **Excel** in **local network** but when I run it  i have an error of compilation

```
Public Function AllowNetworkLocations()
Dim strLnKey As String
Dim reg As Object

Set reg = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
strLnKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations\AllowNetworkLocations"
reg.RegWrite strLnKey, 1, "REG_DWORD"
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: See http://www.devhut.net/2010/06/23/vbscript-createset-trusted-location-using-vbscript/

Comment: it would be enough to write only
 
`Set reg = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
strLnKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations\AllowNetworkLocations"
reg.RegWrite strLnKey, 1, "REG_DWORD"`"